# Does it make any difference with passive auxiliary or not?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

> Jose Arcadio Segundo, in the meantime, had satisfied his wish to see a shooting. For the rest of his life he would remember the livid flash of the six simultaneous shots-and the echo of the discharge as it broke against the hills and the sad smile and perplexed eyes of the man **being shot**, who stood erect while his shirt became soaked with blood, and who was still smiling even when they untied him from the post and put him in a box filled with quicklime.   (One Hundred Years of Solitude, tr. by Gregory Rabassa)

Can you substitute *being shot* with *shot*? If yes, isn't there any semantic difference?
Since *being* is an auxiliary used for passive construction, I don't think there is some difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *being shot* and *shot* are, as you say, semantically passive. The difference is one of **aspect**: bare *shot* is a perfective form, *being shot* is an imperfective progressive construction.

That is, if you expand these two reduced relatives you get

> ... the man who was shot ...
>   ... the man who was being shot ...

The construction without *being* would represent Segundo's memory of the smile on the face of the man after he had been shot.

The construction with *being* represents Segundo's memory of the man smiling as he was being shot, and is necessary because it is followed by Segundo's memory that the man *was **still** smiling* after he had been shot and was cut down.